# CallPowershell API URL

Tags: powershell

My PowerShell version is 4.0.

Below is the procedure I tried :

URL Contains the Query

```
$url="https://fm.clouddam.microsoft.com/api/entities/query/Definition.Name=='M.Asset'ANDDateTime('CreatedOn')lt2016-03-28?take=0"
```

Invoke-RestMethod $url

**Output** :  html code

BUt I need the downloadable file to be saved from the URL and get the output from json data in that file

[How to download file and save in some path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roa58.png)

Help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ConvertFrom-Json](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=217031) cmdlet to convert the json into an `PSCustomObject` and just select the `total_items`:

```
'{"items":[],"total_items":4677,"returned_items":0,"offset":0}' | ConvertFrom-Json | select -ExpandProperty
```

Note: Use the [Get-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113310) cmdlet if you need to retrieve the json string from a file:

```
Get-Content 'PATH_TO_THE_JSON_FILE' | ConvertFrom-Json | select -ExpandProperty
```

*Result:*

```
4677
```

Comment: Thanks for response
We have a URL "https://fm.clouddam.microsoft.com/api/entities/query/Definition.Name=='M.Asset'ANDDateTime('CreatedOn')lt2016-03-28?take=0"
when we click we get a file downloaded which gives the below text in it

{"items":[],"total_items":4677,"returned_items":0,"offset":0}

i have to code for all URL's and get the respective total_items for all.

Comment: So you also need to read the text file? I edited my answer. Please take your time to describe exactly what you want and what you tried within your questions.

Comment: Is it clear or any other information needs to be added :)

Comment: No am trying PowerShell script  to login on the page first and then invoke rest method can be used to get the JSON script as per my analysis.